# Avoid empty lines between a select result on PL/SQL command line

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

OK this is weird, but most have some reason...

When I execute a normal select:

```
SELECT * FROM footable foo;
```

On PS/SQL command line from allroundautomations 10.0.2.1697 on a 10g Oracle it results on expected lines BUT in between some empty lines are put in between, something like this:

```
FOO_COD_ID         FOO_IDT_TYPE         FOO_VALUE
<previous lines>
.......689....................1...............'0'
.................................................
.................................................
.................................................
................<empty lines>....................
.................................................
.................................................
.................................................
.................................................
.......690....................1...............'0'
.......691....................1...............'0'
.......692....................1...............'0'
<et cetera>
```

When executing PL/SQL informs: `476 row selected in x seconds` and those empty lines are put between the results, but always in the same place, between `FOO_COD_ID` 689 and 690.

The SAME select on SQL window doesn't end up with empty lines between the results and also shows the same message `476 row selected in x seconds`, i.e., those empty lines are not counted, but why is this and how to avoid.

Comment: Perhaps one of your column values has carriage return/line feed characters.

Comment: PL/SQL is a programming language. So what exactly do you mean with "*On PS/SQL command line*"? Are you referring to commandline from `SQL*Plus`? And what do you mean with "on SQL window" and "PL/SQL informs"?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i think he's talking about PL/SQL Developer, and IDE similar to Toad from a company called all around automations.

Comment: exactly @tbone . "15 characters in length boring rule. Here is your chars"

Comment: @GordonLinoff excellent, that's the reason! I looked as hexa char value and captured. want to put it as a response?

Comment: @RodrigoGurgel you dont wanna those lines?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar we concluded, thanks Gordon Linoff, that those lines are part of a field ('\n'), but, if you know how to avoid extra lines on command line's results, you can set it as a response, then I'll check it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) commentaries I figured out that those empty lines were caused by some line breaks/feeds  in a specific `varchar` field.